# MariaDb and Peewee

Tags: python, mariadb, peewee

I want to use MariaDb for my flask app. 
So I try to make connection like in documentation, are any orm which support this db?
Does peewee support MariaDb. How can i use peewee orm for connection to MariaDb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it supports MariaDB in the same way that it supports MySQL. MariaDB speaks the mysql protocol and uses the mysql drivers. So just use `MySQLDatabase`.